# NetCDF transformation

Tags: qgis, gdal, coordinate-system, netcdf

I have NetCDF files with some datasets with data and two datasets containing lons and lats. I would like to open data layers in QGIS in coordinates that are written in NetCDF's lon/lat datasets. How could I do that?

What I am trying to do is transform NetCDF data to another coordinate system in another grid, then save it as TIFF. I wanted to use QGIS first to see what steps should I make.

Answer (score 1):

When you open netCDF in QGIS, you open it as a Raster layer (*.NC/*.nc) which then tells you about its sub-layers which you can add as data layers.

Once open you can extract the grid the raster is built with and associate the data layers with the grid.  Look at flood filling algorithms too, for filling arrays with data from the netCDF.

Personally, I'd do this with GDAL or ArcPy as it's relatively easy with both.

Comment: Thanks, I check that out tomorrow. I didn't make myself clear, I want to use GDAL (or other tool) to write script for that. Which GDAL tools should I look for?

Comment: Just using GDAL/OGR means you can open a netCDF, it just do sit.  Load the libraries and open it up.

Comment: Thank You for answers, I couldn't associate my data layers with grid in QGIS. I moved my task a bit further and figured a new question. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171391/regridding-vector-values .

Comment: Hi Kazik, I'll look at that question now. However, as a new user, could I remind you to up-mark answers that help you, as that's how the concept of this works.  Thanks