# Regridding vector values

Tags: python, vector, interpolation, coordinate-system

I'm trying to regrid and interpolate vector values from WAM model output.

I got WAM model netCDF output in rotated grid, I need to interpolate it to another grid which is some variant of LAEA projection.

For scalar values I used SCRIP (Spherical Coordinate Remapping and Interpolation Package) to produce remap source and destination addresses and coefficients. Then I used the result .nc file to make interpolation in python (i.e. to make final nc files in output grid).

Now what should I do to regrid vector? Should I rotate it before regridding? I suppose interpolating u,v vector components the same way I did with scalars isn't a way to go.

I thought that I could use python cartopy.vector_transform, but I'm not sure how to specify my source Coordinate Reference System (https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/blob/master/lib/cartopy/vector_transform.py)

Are there some tools that would let me do that?